# Переменные в переменной, ошибка syntax

Tags: php

Нужно занести переменные в одну переменную, чтобы на выходе получилось вот так:

```
2016-05-24 16:32:45
```

Код у меня такой:

```
$date = $d_y.-.$d_m.-.$d_d. .$d_c.:.$d_mm.:.$d_s;
```

Ошибка выходит вот такая: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in`

Как ее исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Окружите дефисы, пробел и двоеточия кавычками, например так:

```
$date = $d_y."-".$d_m."-".$d_d." ".$d_c.":".$d_mm.":".$d_s;
```

Еще проверьте, что в формуле с правой стороны стоят строки, или сделайте в начале формулы жесткое приведение типов - указать перед переменной (string) или заключить ее в двойные кавычки (не одинарные), например - "$d_y"."-"."$d_m" и т.д.

Comment: Все работает отлично, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно все выражение в двойные кавычки поместить, в этом случае интерпретатор преобразует переменные в их значения:

```
 $date = "$d_y-$d_m-$d_d $d_c:$d_mm:$d_s";
```